# Python Argparse and Kwargs: How to appropriately specify defaults?

Tags: python

I am following a recipe like this:

`script.py`

```py
def foo(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
    ...

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--a', type=int, default=1)
parser.add_argument('--b', type=int, default=2)
parser.add_argument('--c', type=int, default=3)
parser.add_argument('--d', type=int, default=4)
args = parser.parse_args() # get arguments as Namespace object
kwargs = vars(args) # convert to dictionary
foo(**kwargs) # unpack dictionary into kwargs
```

Then I run it from the command line using something like:

```sh
python script.py --a 2 --c 5
```

to optionally override defaults.

The default arguments in `foo` provide hints to the user on:

- reasonable default values
- the types we expect the arguments to be
  However, we also get this from the `parser.add_argument` call.

This violates DRY and can be hard to maintain when you have upwards of 20 kwargs.

---

**What is the clearest way to convey the default type and value while still being able to run my code this way?**

Comment: Define the defaults as constants? `DEFAULT_A = 1`, then reference `DEFAULT_A` in `add_argument` and `foo()`, etc.

Comment: Is this the most pythonic approach? Are constants like that normally defined in their own file?

Comment: Sharing defaults across different APIs (argparse is not the only such an API) in the same codebase is a common theme. Where you keep the defaults is up to you, it depends on the project size if that's a separate `constants.py` in the package or in the module directly.

Comment: Not nearly as portable and legible, but you can use introspection of the function object to get the default kwargs.

Comment: @MadPhysicist good to know, thank you. Martin, I will probably do what you suggested.